# Trying to code for the first time, but failed with file location

Tags: vbscript

The problem is that I tried to make a file on somebody else's desktop but I don't know what to write in the users.

I tried `"C:\Users\" & strUser & "\desktop\Test"`

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")
  fso.Createfolder "C:\Users\" & strUser & "\desktop\Test"
```

> error: Can't find the file location.

Comment: You said you tried to make a file on the Desktop. When you go to the Desktop... is it there? It's name is "Test" is it? Is it Test.txt or Test.vb or something else?  This question I believe is better suited to the SuperUser Stackexchange site because you do need the ability to locate your own files as a programmer.

Comment: " idk what to write in the users". Are you talking about the Command Prompt? Windows+R -> cmd ?

Comment: Unless user under which program is running has admin-privileges its unlikely that it can access another user's desktop. Perhaps that is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Use the special folder Shell function to return the path to the desktop.

```
set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
strDesktopPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject") 
fso.Createfolder strDesktopPath & "\Test"
```

Comment: This will return the current user's Desktop folder. The question is about somebody else's Desktop.

Comment: Thank you that helped Lost bard, but i am new to coding and i don't realy know what

Comment: set, sub, if, end if, then, and so on means

Comment: yeah I missed the comment of 'somebody elses'

Answer (score 0):

I think your code will work if you simply add a `\` at the end of your path:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")
fso.Createfolder "C:\Users\" & strUser & "\desktop\Test\"
```

Comment: Glad it solved your problem. Please mark the question as answered when you get a chance and come back to Stack Overflow when you run into other programming problems.